# ffmpeg: create a webm video with changing resolution from a sequence of images

Tags: ffmpeg, video, resolution

There's a funny thing going on with webm videos being able to have an aspect ratio that changes while it's being played, as shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/y-mh5lPy6KU?t=32), and I figured i'd try my hand at making one. I rendered out a few hundred frames which progressively get taller and tried to stick them together using

`ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -i frame%04d.png -codec vp8 -crf 25  -pix_fmt yuv420p output.webm`

Unfortunately, this renders the video at the resolution of the first frame, and squeezes the others down to that resolution. Is there any way that I could allow ffmpeg to make a video with changing resolutions, or is that not supported?